# ¿Problema con interrupciones en Arduino Ensamblador?

Tags: arduino, ensamblador

Hola Amigos como están? Espero que estén muy bien, tengo el siguiente problema en ensamblador, cuando quiero que en la interrupción el LED 1 parpadee 5 veces por alguna razón me lo hace 10 veces, si pongo que lo haga 4 lo hace 8 veces, no se por que me esta duplicando todo.(Tengo un arduino uno chino) Saludos amigos

```
.INCLUDE "m328pdef.inc"

.CSEG                           ;COMIENZO ESCRITURA EN ROM
.ORG 0X0000                     ;INICIO DE LA ROM
    JMP CONFIGURACIONES

.ORG INT0addr                   ;ES LA POSICION 0X02
    JMP INTERRUPCION

.ORG INT_VECTORS_SIZE           ;52 WORDS EN 328P

CONFIGURACIONES
    LDI R16,0XFF                ;CONFIGURO EL PUERTO B
    OUT DDRB,R16                ;CONFIGURO EL PUERTO B COMO SALIDA
    LDI R16,0X00    
    OUT PORTB,R16               ;PONGO TODO EN CERO

    LDI R16,(1<<ISC01|0<<ISC00) ;CONF INT0 POR FLANCO DESCENDENTE
    STS EICRA,R16               ;SETEO INT0 EN 0X69
    CLR R16
    LDI R16,(1<<INT0)           ;ACTIVO INT0
    OUT EIMSK,R16               ;PASO EL REG A 0X1D
    CLR R16

    SEI                         ;HABILITO INTERRUPCIONES

MAIN:
    SBI PORTB,0                 ;ENCIENDE EL LED 0
    JMP MAIN

INTERRUPCION:
    CLI
    CBI PORTB,0                 ;APAGO EL LED 0
    LDI R17,0x05

PARPADEO:
    DEC R17 
    SBI PORTB,1
    CALL DELAY
    CBI PORTB,1
    CALL DELAY
    CPI R17,0
    BRNE PARPADEO

    SBI PORTB,0
    SEI
    RETI

DELAY:                          ;CONFIGURO EL DELAY

    LDI R20, 32
t3: LDI R19, 250
t2: LDI R18, 250
t1: NOP                         ; hasta aca son 4 ciclos de maquina por iteracion -> 250ns

    DEC R18                     ; 250 x 250ns = 62.5us
    BRNE t1

    DEC R19
    BRNE t2                     ; 250 x 50us = 15.625ms

    DEC R20
    BRNE t3                     ; 32 x 15.625ms = 500ms 
                                ; Con esto logre un retardo de Medio Segundo
    RET                         ; Vuelve a la linea siguiente de la que fue llamado
```